# Problems importing SQL script from Oracle 9i to Oracle 10g express

Tags: import, oracle10g, ddl, oracle9i

I am currently running into a problem when trying to import an Oracle 9i SQL script into my local Oracle 10g Express database. I am trying to import the [DDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Definition_Language) from the 9i database to the 10g express database. I keep getting "Not compatible - Your export file is not supported". Has someone been able to get this working? Please let me know what I can do to get this working.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're exporting and importing with the same version of exp and imp and also make sure that that version corresponds to the lower version of both databases, in your case: 9i.

Maybe, you should explicitely state the path to imp and exp like /path/to/oracle/bin/exp .

Hope this helps
Rene

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to run the import utility on a .sql script? Or Import an Exported file?

If the latter, prior answers are acceptable. If the former, run your create script through SQLPLUS, PlsqlDeveloper, TOAD, SQLDeveloper or whatever you use to run ddl statements.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully imported an Oracle 9 export (created with the 'exp' utility) into an Oracle 10 database (using the 'imp' utility) thismorning. It worked perfectly.

Can you give more information? e.g. output of the set of commands that you run, an example of the file or any more details?